# Program received SIGSEGV - invalid memory reference

Tags: windows, io, linker, mingw, gfortran

I wrote a small linker in fortran-cpp to read a file with some numbers.

```fortran
  $cat mainProg.f

  program fprogram
  real*8 c(30)

  do i=1,30
     c(i) = i * 1.0
  end do
  print*,"Before calling cpp function"
  c PASS ARRAY "C" TO CPP
  call pass_to_cpp(c)
  print*,"After calling cpp function"
  do i=1,30
     print*,' c =',c(i)
  end do

  print*,"I'm done here ..!!"
  c      stop
  end
```

and,

```cxx
  $cat cprog.C

  #include<iostream>
  #include<cmath>
  #include<fstream>
  using namespace std;

  extern "C" {
        void pass_to_cpp_(double *c);
  }
  void pass_to_cpp_(double *c)
  {
    ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        myfile >> c[i];
        cout <<"called = " << i << "\n";
    }
  }
```

I am building this on ubuntu 16.04 to be run on a windows machine. I am usin mingw for compiling.

Here is the error on windows:

```
   called = 0
   Program received a signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference
   Backtrace for this error:
   #0 ffffffffffffff
   #1 ffffffffffffff
   #2 ffffffffffffff
   #3 ffffffffffffff
   #4 ffffffffffffff
   #5 ffffffffffffff
   #6 ffffffffffffff
   #7 ffffffffffffff
   #8 ffffffffffffff
   #9 ffffffffffffff
   #10 ffffffffffffff
   #11 ffffffffffffff
   #12 ffffffffffffff
   #13 ffffffffffffff
   #14 ffffffffffffff
   #15 ffffffffffffff
```

File 'example.txt' is a simple file with 30 numbers.

Any suggestions on what is the cause of the error?

I compiled with this:

```
    $ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -c main_read.f
    $ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -c cread.C
    $ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -o read.exe main_read.o cread.o -lstdc++ -static
```

If I dont use -static, it complains 'libgfortran3.dll not found'.

Comment: How do you build and link your program?

Comment: `$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -c main_read.f`        `$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -c cread.C `          `$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -o read.exe main_read.o cread.o -lstdc++ -static`

Comment: And what is the complaint? Perhaps that could be relevant to the problem? Also please edit your question to include this information (and how you build).

Comment: I added those  instructions

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need a separate declaration and definition of the `pass_to_cpp_` function. You can use `extern "C"` in the definition, as `extern "C" void pass_to_cpp_(double *c) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, I was following an example from a book.. but the error still persists